# WordPress wp_enqueue_ scripts not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem enqueing a superfish script into my website. I've been hours around it and I have no idea what's causing the problem. I'm using a theme based on underscroes (this is my second time using it) and I enqueue the script in the functions.php using the

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'kornelije-stankovic-superfish', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.js', array('jquery'), '20140711', true );
```

I load the website using Chrome, check the resources and the script doesn't load. Of course the script is in the /js folder with that exact name superfish.js.

The funny thing is, that I tried loading it on the other website in the exact same manner and it works just fine!

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_enqueue_script()` should be called inside a `wp_enqueue_scripts` callback, just like this:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Code from the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

---

### Edit

I would suggest you put the function call `wp_enqueue_script( 'kor...` inside the `_s_scripts()` in the `functions.php` file (the function would have `_s` replaced with your theme name ).

Comment: It's inside the function. It's just below others. I have a script below the superfish one which loads just fine. Something is blocking it and I have no idea what.

Comment: @user3088451 the check the value of the path with `echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.js'; exit;` and see if it's correct

Comment: ugh... it seems like wp super cache caused the issue. My website was not upadting it seems with what I told him to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has been a WP Super Cache "problem."

It was on so the page wasn't refreshing instantly.

Thanks for help.